How was Laplace able to propose the Laplace expansion?
I read Sylvester's 1850 paper, which is on file here. If you look at page 147 of this file, you will see the following sentence:

Imagine any determinant set out under the form of a square array of
terms. This square may be considered as divisible into lines and columns.
Now conceive any one line and any one column to be struck out, we get
in this way a square, one term less in breadth and depth than the original
square; and by varying in every possible manner the selection of the line
and column excluded, we obtain, supposing the original square to consist of
$n$ lines and $n$ columns, $n^2$ such minor squares, each of which will represent
what I term a First Minor Determinant relative to the principal or complete
determinant.

I know that the first appearance of the term minor in matrices theory was in Sylvester's 1850 paper.  However, Laplace proposed the Laplace expansion in 1772.  However, minor is a necessary concept for cofactor expansion.  So, my question is that the timing was not favorable for Laplace to propose the Laplace expansion, so I wonder what kind of mathematical background, that is, what mathematical tools existed at the time when Laplace lived, that allowed him to succeed in proposing the Laplace expansion.

Muir, T. (1890). The theory of determinants in the historical order of development, part I (1693-1841). Macmillan pp.23-33. contains an exposition of Laplace's work on 1772. Laplace's context is solving systems of linear equations which predates the strong formulation of the concept of the determinants, and reducing the number of unknowns amounts to reducing to a minor determinant. None of these terms were known to Laplace. However work by Cramer, Bezout and Vandermonde were known to him. See Muir for details.
